# update and show comment without reloading the webpage

Tags: php, jquery

i have the following jquery code, which is link to a html form which is link to a php script. the form should submit and the jquery code should update the comment and show the comment as if the page was referesh. but nothing happens when i hit submit i cant seem to see where or what i am doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    //When submit button clicked
    $('#submit').click(function(){

        //Getting data from input fields
        var sentby_val = $('#sent_by').val();
        var message_val = $('#message').val();

        $.post('comment.php', { username: sentby_val, message: message_val }, function(return_data){

            //Response from script when comment inserted to database
            alert(return_data);

            //Clean fields
            $('#sent_by').val('<?php print $_SESSION['email']?>');
            $('#message').val('');

        });

    });
});

</script>
```

here is the html form

```
<form  action='comment.php' method='post' style="width: 422px">
    <input type='hidden' id="sent_by" name='sent_by' value="<?php print $_SESSION['email']?>"/>
    <input type='hidden' id="hidden_id"  name='hidden_id' value='<?php print $picid;?>'/>
    <textarea name='message' id="message" value="make your comment" style="width: 450px; height: 70px">make your comment</textarea><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='sub'  value='comment' id="submit" style="border-style:none; float:right;" />
</form>
```

here is the comment.php // which shouldnt really be the problem

```
<?
$name = $_POST['sent_by'];
$picid= $_POST['hidden_id'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$sub = $_POST['sub'];

if ($sub){if($name&&$message&&$picid)
{
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,message,picid) VALUES ('$name','$message','$picid')" );
}
else
{ 
    echo "Please enter a comment"; 
}

header("location:../profile.php?pic=$id");
?>
```

please help what am i missing or not seeing

Comment: please make sure your code is formatted correctly. if you don't it is very difficult to read and we don't know if everything is there.

Comment: You should use firebug to check your ajax response.  It's cleaner than an `alert`.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should be really careful here as you are leaving yourself WIDE open for SQL injection style attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    //When submit button clicked
    $('#submit').click(function(){

        //Getting data from input fields
        var sentby_val = $('#sent_by').val();
        var message_val = $('#message').val();

        $.post('comment.php', { username: sentby_val, message: message_val }, function(return_data){

            //Response from script when comment inserted to database
            alert(return_data);

            //Clean fields
            $('#sent_by').val('<?php print $_SESSION['email']?>');
            $('#message').val('');

        });

        // Overrides default click handler.
        // Without this the form will be submitted
        return false;

    });
});

</script>
```